# (WPF) How to change ListBox items/headers font size at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, styles

I want to allow user to change the font size a listbox during runtime. What's the simplest way to achieve that? (also, is there a way to simplify the code in general?)

Here's a xaml for the list I have: https://pastebin.com/Y8q5W50S

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="CardsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=placement}" 
         Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle}">
                                    <Expander.Header>                                                
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PlacementHeaderStyle}" />                                               
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter IsEnabled="False" />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                           
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=power}" Style="{StaticResource CardPowerStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=name}" Style="{StaticResource CardNameStyle}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Your title seems unrelated to the question you're asking. Please clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also if you want general code review you should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Resize how? Like, "zoom in" type resize, or just increase the font size or something?

Comment: Bind the font size into your Textblock from the view model. And keep the value in View Model. Set some command to increase and decrease the value of font size do not forget about implement INotifyProperty change in View Model. Let me know if you need an example

Comment: @Joe just increase the font size, as I said in the question title

Comment: @macieqqq I'd love to see an example, I'm new to wpf

Comment: @EdPlunkett I want to change the font size of the items and headers of the listbox at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

So here is an example: Size of the font inside the item template of the ListBox is binded from ViewModel. The same value is also binded to slider so you can check how it works and change it on runtime.

First, you will have to create the view model where you will have to keep the value of font size. The view model will have to implement INotify property changed.

```
  public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string> {"item1", "item2"};
        _fontSize = 12d;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

    private double _fontSize;

    public double FontSize
    {
        get => _fontSize;
        set
        {
            _fontSize = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FontSize));
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChangedImplementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Next step is to set view model as view data context for example like this ( Please, checkout for example, Caliburn Micro or Prism to make this automatically).

```
 /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

After that bind the font size to the list using a relative source binding from ListBox item template to window DataContext ( MainWindowViewModel).

Ex:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBindingWpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBindingWpfApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Font size slider:"></TextBlock>
        <Slider Maximum="30" Minimum="5" Value="{Binding FontSize}"/>

    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1"  Name="CardsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" 
     Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="{Binding DataContext.FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I have attached working project.

Sorry for the not detailed description I will update it later.

[Sample Project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av3tBzzBBCzYiIB9xmn5GgUpmVQF3g)